# Svg with pointer events not working in safari

Tags: css, svg

I have been working with SVG elements ( shapes ), and in cases I have to allow the mouse clicks to pass through those elements where it is transparent or say there are no actual shape.

To achieve this I have used pointer-events:none the css property to the root SVG tag, this works fine in Most of the browsers including IE and Mozilla too.

But Safari seems to have no affect of this css property.
Here is the fiddle to check :

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/AkashSaikia/52aWw/2/'
```

Does any body has idea about this ? Or a work around for this ?

Comment: which version of safari you are using ? this link says it should support `http://caniuse.com/pointer-events` in latest version

Comment: @MarmiK I am using Safari 5.1.7 in Windows Machine.

Comment: Try blank instead of auto, as it may be safari bug, it does not work on iPad's too specifically with SVG element. may be path element

Answer (score 1):

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/52aWw/3/) with rect element in SVG Please check if it's working.

```
<rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.3; " fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" height="20" width="80"  stroke-width="10" x=2 y=2 opacity="0.3"></rect>
```

The problem is with Safari with SVG element although it says it supports but does not support 100% extensions/tags of the same..

You can also change the DocType if that works,

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN” “http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd”>
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: It did not work with your changed jsfiddle, it also did not work with changes in DocType declaration. Did it work in your case? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example that works on all browsers and safari on iPad

See this page

http://www.janvas.com/illustrators_designers_developers/projects/janvas2D_web/examples_EN.php?exampleName=green_monster_game_EN

at the line 121 of the javascript code there is:

cloned_explosion_sprite.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

this line make off the mouse/touch event for the explosion sprite that, when added to the dom, stays between the mouse and others monsters.

Let me know

Comment: the code is into the page down scroll please, have you seen it ?

Comment: yes i have seen the code, but you know to debug that code that too with the thing that stays for a minimal time is difficult. Can you share/implement that code with the fiddle that i have included in the question?